# Unable to build Qt 5.9.0 with Android

Tags: android, qt, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, qt5.9

I am facing issue while compiling Qt with android.Kindly help me to solve this issue.

**issue :**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >   Could not get resource 'https: //jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https:// jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >   Could not get resource 'https:// maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https: //maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.26.163] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 46.542 secs
>   Building the android package failed!
>     -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
>   10:51:50: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.9.0\5.9\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
>   Error while building/deploying project calqlatr (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.0 for Android armv7))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

**gradle.build:**

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { jcenter() } 
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' } 
} 

allprojects { 
     repositories { jcenter() } 
} 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
dependencies { 
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
 androidBuildToolsVersion=26.0.0 androidCompileSdkVersion=18 buildDir=build qt5AndroidDir=C:/Qt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/src/android/ja‌​va
```

Comment: The link is correct. Check your connection

Comment: Hi Gabriele mariotte, Thanks for reply. Check connection means? internet is working properly . i need to check proxy settings? if so.. what changes i have to do ? it will be reply help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If you are using a proxy, you have to set the proxy also for gradle (or your IDE)

Comment: Hi Gabriele. i am not using any proxy settings, i faced some issues while compiling  so i changed as below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603811/error-while-compiling-qt-5-9-0-with-android after that i started getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

now it Generated apk files and able see application in emulator.

**solution which worked for me** :

**unchecked** use gradle instead of ant in Qt tools option.

**unchecked** Use gradle option in Qt projects(Build Android APK).